# Boolean "sum" in XSLT

Tags: xslt, boolean

I know I can sum over multiple nodes with numeric values.
How could I do a "boolean sum" over a set of nodes? For example:

```
<a>
  <b>false</b>
  <b>false</b>
  <b>true</b>
  <b>false</b>
</a>
```

How could I get the boolean OR of all the `<b>` node values? (which should be 'true').

Comment: Today I also learned that the output in XML of false(), that is the string 'false', itself has the boolean value true().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
boolean(/*/b[. = 'true'])
```

**This produces the boolean value of the expression**:

```
 /*/b[. = 'true']
```

**and is true exactly when the above expression selects at least one node** -- that is, when there is a `b` that is a child of the top element and whose string value is the string `'true`.

---

**In case you want also to calculate the "boolean product" (using *and*), do:**

```
not(/*/b[. = 'false'])
```

Comment: Great! I was afraid I would have enter the jungle of recursive templates. So grateful that it can be put in a single expression AND for the "boolean product" as well.

Comment: @Justsalt, You are welcome. And yes, XPath is a great language.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the true values:

```
<xsl:if test="count(a/b[text()='true']) > 0">
        true
</xsl:if>
```

If there are any true values the OR will be true.

Comment: If it's based on text, you don't need to count: `/a/b[.='true']`